# statistics on what queries were executed and how many times

Tags: mysql, mariadb, statistics

I'd like to monitor how many times certain queries are executed. Take a look at the 3 queries below, the second and third are written as prepared statement.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE1

UPDATE TABLE2 SET `last_parsed` = NOW() WHERE `id` = ?

SELECT 1 FROM TABLE2 WHERE (`last_parsed` IS NULL OR `last_parsed` < DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 7 DAY)) AND `id` = ?
```

Does mariadb/mysql dbms keep track of how many times each query is executed? Does it group the prepared statements into one listing, so that if `id` is 10 or 20, they both show under the same category?

Comment: *Does mariadb/mysql dbms keep track of how many times each query is executed?* No. You may get and aggregate this info from General Log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL and MariaDB...

Plan A:  Turn on the slowlog.  Have `long_query_time = 0`.  Use `pt-query-digest` to summarize the log.  (This will also provide info on poorly performing queries.)

Plan B:  Turn on the general log.  Use `pt-query-digest` to summarize the log.

Caution:  Both techniques use a lot of disk space and do not clean up after themselves.  That is, you will need to deal with the disk space used. if you run this for a long time.

The 'digest' removes actual numeric and string values.  That is "... WHERE x=2" and "... WHERE x=987" are considered the "same".  If you need "same" to include same values, then you should plan on using the general log and do your own post-processing.